# Not able to clear text box values and print success message after saving data in to database using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a new learner of mvc dot net. I was not Not able to clear text box values and print success message after saving data in to database using entity framework. I have created model data using entity framework.

Below is my controller and action method.

```
 public ActionResult Registration(BookStoreMvc.Models.user obj)

        {
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    BookStoreMvc.Models.bookstoreEntities3 db = new BookStoreMvc.Models.bookstoreEntities3();


                    db.users.Add(obj);

                    int a = 0;

                    a=db.SaveChanges();

                    if (a>0)
                    {
                        ViewData["Message"] = "Data saved successfully";
                    }


                    this.ModelState.Clear();
                }
     
                return View(obj);
               }
        }
```

And below is the code which written in view.

```
  @if(@Model!= null)
  {
      @ViewData["Message"].ToString();
  }
</div>
```

Any one help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way.

```
@if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
{
    ViewData["Message"].ToString();
}
```